# AWS SNS Android GCM - InvalidPlatformToken

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, xamarin, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Using Xamarin and AWS SNS trying to get push notifications working. They were working just fine the other day. Today they aren't.

I have an Android device and an iOS device. Whenever I change anything in my application the other device is supposed to get a push notification. The iOS device is working.

C# code for subscribing on Android:

```
[Service(Exported = false)]
public class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
{
    static object locker = new object();

    public RegistrationIntentService() : base("RegistrationIntentService") { }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken");
            lock (locker)
            {
                var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance(this);
                var token = instanceID.GetToken(
                    "shhh it's a secret.", GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

                Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
                SendRegistrationToAppServer(token);
                Subscribe(token);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug("RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to get a registration token");
            return;
        }
    }

    void SendRegistrationToAppServer(string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation here as needed.
        //... handling my token on the back-end
    }

    void Subscribe(string token)
    {
        var pubSub = GcmPubSub.GetInstance(this);
        pubSub.Subscribe(token, "/topics/global", null);
    }
}
```

Dropping some breakpoints in there I can see that my device token does match the token for the AWS endpoint that I'm trying to send messages to. For some reason though, I keep getting error messages back from AWS. This is what AWS is sending me:

`{"DeliveryAttempts":1,"EndpointArn":"arn:aws:sns:...:endpoint/GCM/...","EventType":"DeliveryFailure","FailureMessage":"Platform token associated with the endpoint is not valid","FailureType":"InvalidPlatformToken","MessageId":"...","Resource":"arn:aws:sns:...:app/GCM/...","Service":"SNS","Time":"2016-03-28T18:22:59.360Z"}`

What could be causing this if I know the token I'm getting back from the application matches the token of my AWS endpoint?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm hitting exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that the registration id that is being passed to the SNS is not correct. I would recommend that you turn on the delivery status and see the actual response from GCM, see https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxHTXGC8711JNF/Using-the-Delivery-Status-feature-of-Amazon-SNS for information